# Show that $\max_i\left\{|v_i| + |w_i|\right\} \leq \max_i\left\{|v_i|\right\} + \max_i\left\{|w_i|\right\}$.

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

While trying to prove that the $\infty$-norm of a vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$ does satisfy the properties of being a norm, I inevitably came across the following inequality:

$\max_i\left\{|v_i| + |w_i|\right\} \leq \max_i\left\{|v_i|\right\} + \max_i\left\{|w_i|\right\}$.

I deduced from examples that the equality holds if and only if the indices of the largest elements of both vectors $\vec{v}$ and $\vec{w}$ are the same. But I do not know how to provide a general proof for the inequality without resorting to proof by example or case by case analysis.

Could anyone shed some light?

Comment: Start with $\lvert v_i\rvert + \lvert w_i\rvert \leqslant \lvert v_i\rvert + \max_j \lvert w_j\rvert \leqslant \max_k \lvert v_k\rvert + \max_j \lvert w_j\rvert$. Do you see how to finish?

Comment: It follows directly that $\max_i\{|v_i| + |w_i|\} \leq \max_k|v_k| + \max_j\|v_j\|$. Your hint succinctly captures the thought process which I struggled to express concisely. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For each $i$, $$|v_i|\leq\max_i\{|v_i|\}\quad\&\quad |w_i|\leq\max_i\{|w_i|\}.$$ Hence for each $i$ $$|v_i|+|w_i|\leq\max_i\{|v_i|\}+\max_i\{|w_i|\}. $$ Now there exists $m$ such that, $\max \{|v_i|+|w_i|\}=|v_m|+|w_m|$. Put $i=m$ in the above inequality.